# Новые записи не появляются в БД после вставки

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, sqlite

Сделал функцию, загрузки пользователей ВК из беседы в БД (SQLite). Одновременно работаю с vk_api.
Вот код, ошибок в консоли ни каких нету и в БД ничего не происходит, ни каких изменений.

```
def loadDB():

    import sqlite3

    Connect = sqlite3.connect("CaptureBotDB.db")
    Cursor = Connect.cursor()

    peer_id = event.obj.get('peer_id')
    chat = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(peer_id=peer_id)

    for members in chat['profiles']:

        first_name = str(members['first_name'])
        last_name = str(members['last_name'])
        user_id = str(members['id'])

        sql = """INSERT INTO ListMembers (first_name, last_name, user_id) VALUES (?,?,?)"""
        Cursor.execute(sql, (str(first_name), str(last_name), str(user_id)))
```

Проверил для начала вод этот кусок кода, работает ли вовсе:

```
        first_name = str(members['first_name'])
        last_name = str(members['last_name'])
        user_id = str(members['id'])

        print(str(first_name) + str(last_name) + str(user_id))
```

Всё выводит: (Это список пользователей беседы)

```
СтепанЗеленин154845243
UserGames434495547
KarlRendal539995337
```

Видимо, что-то не так я сделал с частью SQLite. Что не так?

Comment: Вы делали „commit” после вставки данных?

Comment: @MaxU, Кхе. Нет. :с

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изменения надо зафиксировать:

```
Connect.commit()
```

Comment: Я уже понял, да. Спасибо Вам! За сегодняшний день Вы меня прям сильно выручили! Спасибо большое!))))

Comment: Всё отлично работает.